# ROS to ABB IRC5 controller pendant error unknown ROS_msg

Tags: ros, abb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have follow this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/abb/Tutorials/InstallServer)  for the ABB robot. However, after restarting the controller I am getting this error on my pendant screen.

**Error in T_ROB1-ROS_socket-Line 55**

**Description**

Unkown typename

ROS_msg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264255/ros-to-abb-irc5-controller-pendant-error-unknown-ros_msg/) by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2017-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this related to #q263576? If so, then please tell us what you ended up doing: are you still using the Hydro version of everything? Which tutorial(s) did you follow to set everything up?

From your description it could be that you haven't correctly copied everything (ie: the `rapid` files) onto the controller.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2017-06-21**:
Yes, the hydro version is used. This is the [link](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb/tree/hydro-devel/abb_common/rapid) to the hydro version. I created a ROS folder and place those 6 files into it and copy it into ABB IRC5 controller pendant home folder. Then I did the **Load Modules to Tasks**.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-21**:
Can you verify that the *Automatic Loading of Modules* listing shows everything as described in the tutorial? I've seen controllers that looked like they were correctly configured, but upon closer inspection weren't.

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2017-06-21**:
let me check. Check the name and spelling you meant?